# how to create custom object in salesforce using soap api in java

Tags: soap-api

I have a requirement to create custom object using soap API.
                        Please help me
                                   Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are trying to create the definition of a new custom object, or if you are just trying to insert a new record for an existing custom object.

Answer (score 2):

Using Metadata API you can create new Objects.
Please refer http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/